# Can't run while loop through csv files using python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm having some trouble looping through the code below., Essentially, I am attempting to loop through a folder of files ("filename_x.csv") and remove all commas out within the fields, then I would like for the output to be saved with the "out". The code works like a charm if I input the counter individually, but it will not move to the next count. I know this is very close to functional status, but the 'with' statements may allow the other files to close, so it can't move to the next count or iteration (file path is just an example). Please, help!

```
import pandas as pd

n = 1
x = str(n)

while n < 9:
    import csv
    with open("C:\\Desktop\\server_"+x+".csv",'r', newline='') as infile, open("C:\\Desktop\\server_"+x+"_out.csv",'w', newline='') as outfile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile)
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        for row in reader:
            writer.writerow(item.replace(",", "") for item in row)
            n += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line:

```
x = str(n)
```

is in the wrong place it needs to be in the loop at the top.

You only set at to the initial value of `n` and then it stays that way.

You do not actually even need it. Just put the `str(n)` directly in the string creation like this:

```
"C:\\Desktop\\server_" + str(n) + ".csv"
```

I would also recommend you use a different loop structure. The `while` format you are using does not make sense for the way you are using it. You should be using a `for` loop, like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

for n in range(1, 9):
    with open("C:\\Desktop\\server_" + str(n) + ".csv",'r', newline='') as infile, open("C:\\Desktop\\server_" + str(n) + "_out.csv",'w', newline='') as outfile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile)
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        for row in reader:
            writer.writerow(item.replace(",", "") for item in row)
```

This fixes a few things. You simplify the code, but also there were some other issues. You had the increment of `n` in the wrong place which this corrects. Also you were doing the `import cvs` inside the loop which would probably not break anything, but would at the very least be inefficient since it would attempt reload the `cvs` module every pass through the outer loop.

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback, your edits worked like charm! Looks like I was a little over zealous adding in two separate counters. Still a noob at this :)

Answer (score 0):

Asssuming you have files `server_1.csv`, `server_2.csv` ...

Two things:

1. you don't need to keep track of both `x` and `n`
2. you need to increment `n` in the right place. You are currently incrementing it once per row.

```py
import pandas as pd
import csv # <<< no need to repeat the import statement though it's harmless

n = 1
while n < 9:
    with open("C:\\Desktop\\server_" + str(n) + ".csv",'r', newline='') as infile, open("C:\\Desktop\\server_" + str(n) + "_out.csv",'w', newline='') as outfile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile)
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        for row in reader:
            writer.writerow(item.replace(",", "") for item in row)

        # finished with this file, increment n
        n += 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! You were exactly right in that I needed to increment n in the right place.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation (less than 15) to upvote. Trust me, I've tried. I like how someone downvoted my question though.